# jQuery show a div like slide from right side form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to show my div tag like slide by jquery
this is my html code

```
<div id="resultSearch" class="searchPanel"  style="display:none; position:absolute">
    <div style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt;color:#1376c9;font-weight:bold;">
        //somthing
    </div>
</div>
```

i am using this code for show the resultSearch

```
$('#resultSearch').show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
```

but the tag dose not show!!!
i don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery selector is wrong:

```
$('#resultSearch').show('slide', 
   { 
     direction: 'left' 
   }, 1000);
```

Comment: Are u sure your css positioning that div is correct? (I ask because I see it is positioned absolute)

Answer (score 1):

`locationSearch` is incorrect `id`, the correct `id` is `resultSearch`